# Finding roots of a biquadratic equation

Tags: polynomials

> Suppose that $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ are unequal and not necessarily real. If $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ are the roots of the biquadratic $x^4-x^3+ax^2-8x-8=0$. Find $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$.

I've no idea how to solve this question in an elegant manner. Although it is obvious that if $r_{1}$ is complex then $r_{2}$ is its conjugate, owing to the fact that their product is $2$, I can't even assume the other roots as conjugates of one another as $a$ is not necessarily a real number. I've run out of ideas. Would someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please transcribe the text in the image into the text of your question itself. There is a MathJAX tutoral [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) if you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that one factor of the quartic polynomial will be of the form

$$x^2+px+2,$$ and the other must be of the form $$x^2+qx-4$$ because the constant term is $-8$.

If we expand and identify the cubic and linear terms,

$$\begin{cases}p+q=-1,\\-4p+2q=-8\end{cases}$$ yields the solution

$$\left(x^2+x+2\right)\left(x^2-2x-4\right)=x^4-x^3-4x^2-8x-8.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Yves Daoust

Answer (score 1):

If $r_1r_2 = 2$ it means that $r_1$ and $r_2$ are roots of the polynomial 
$ q(x) = x^2+bx+2 $, where $b=-(r_1+r_2)$. They are also roots of the polynomial $ w(x) = x^4-x^3+ax-8x-8$, which means that $$ x^4-x^3+ax-8x-8 = (x^2+bx+2)(x^2+cx+d) $$
which gives a set of equations $$ b+c = -1 \\ bc+d+2 = a \\ bd +2c = -8 \\
2d = -8 $$
I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If only $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the quartic equation, we have 2 scenarios $$x^4-x^3+ax^2-8x-x=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)^3=0$$or$$x^4-x^3+ax^2-8x-x=(x-r_1)^2(x-r_2)^2=0$$